# Run a function based on the chosen option in a select list? (no jQuery is preferred)

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I've been stuck on this for days, so I greatly appreciate any help you can give.  Here's my problem:

I have a select list:

```
<select id="bandCategories">
  <option>(Choose a category)</option>
  <option>Djent</option>
  <option>Brutal Death Metal</option>
  <option>Deathcore</option>
  <option>Hardcore</option>
  <option>Slam</option>
  <option>Verb the Noun</option>
</select>
```

And here are the variables associated with them:

```
var bandCategories = document.getElementById("bandCategories");
var chooseCategoryStr = bandCategories.options[0].text;
var selectedCategory = bandCategories.options[bandCategories.selectedIndex].text;
```

I have a function called `bgChange()` that I want to run every time the selected option changes, except for when the default "(Choose a category)" is selected. I've tried the following, but to no avail:

```
if(selectedCategory != chooseCategoryStr){
    selectedCategory.onchange = bgChange(selectedCategory);
};
```

Help?

Comment: `selectedCategory` is a string, it has no `onchange`.  Also, it won't update when you select something, you need to get the value each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following JavaScript code should work. No change to your HTML is necessary.

```
var bandCategories = document.getElementById("bandCategories"),
    chooseCategoryStr = bandCategories.options[0].value;

bandCategories.onchange = function () {
    var selectedCategory = this.value;

    if (selectedCategory !== chooseCategoryStr) {
        bgChange(selectedCategory);
    }
};
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gBHJu/) with the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
  <select id="bandCategories" onchange="fun()">
  <option>(Choose a category)</option>
  <option>Djent</option>
  <option>Brutal Death Metal</option>
  <option>Deathcore</option>
  <option>Hardcore</option>
  <option>Slam</option>
  <option>Verb the Noun</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function fun()
    {
        var bandCategories = document.getElementById("bandCategories");
        var chooseCategoryStr = bandCategories.options[0].text;
        var selectedCategory = bandCategories.options[bandCategories.selectedIndex].text;
        if(selectedCategory == chooseCategoryStr){
                return;// no need to call your function bgChange
        }

        alert("bgChange(selectedCategory);"); //Call your function bgChange(selectedCategory);
    }
//-->
</script>
```

You can even add edit in function `bgChange` without adding new function to check the value not equal to `chooseCategoryStr`  before executing your code.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I ended up using the solution above, so I didn't have to mess with the HTML at all :)